# Java: GridBagLayout and GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, oracle

I've had a hard time understanding how GridBagConstraints work. Is everything in a 'column and row' type of state, or is it possible to use exact pixel specifications (x:10 y:20 -> In the corner). Basically I just want to know how this works and if anything I talked about is correct. Thank you.

Some code :/  : (Incorrect code)

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Declaring JFrame, JPanel, JButton
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        JButton button = new JButton("Click me");

        //JFrame, frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //JPanel, panel
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(panel);

        //JButton, button
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1);
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [miglayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)? It can really help to simplify layout of your awt / swing components.

Comment: A `GridBagLayout` is essentially like a table of rows and columns, where the `gridx/y` constraints specify the cell.  You define the constraints for the component in the cell.  A cell whose `weightx/y` property is cell, will effect all the other cells in the column/row, that is, if you make a single cell fill the available width, then all the cells in that column will also be the same width.  It's a highly flexible `GridLayout`.  No, you don't get pixel perfect control, but you can do some tricks to provide some buffering for a component with in individual cells

Answer (score 0):

I believe the part of GridBagLayout and Constraints you are using (grid) is indeed based on rows(x) and columns(y) from the top left corner of the program. There is other ways to do this as well though in the Layout by using gridheight and gridwidth which is slightly different.

Take a read on this for more syntax :)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html